# Windows 10 Start Menu Won't Open due to Firewall being disabled

Tags: windows-10

I've tried many of the [other solutions](https://www.techmesto.com/fix-start-menu-broken-windows-10-technical-preview/) on the web for making the start menu open on Windows 10, but none of them work.  Does anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it a real question. At the moment it is a copy of your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  If you find that the Windows 10 the Start Menu and/or Cortana won't open check to see if your firewall was disabled. There are a [few solutions on the web that may work][1] as well, but I didn't see this solution anywhere on the web.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1000458/my-windows-10-doesnt-show-the-desktop-and-start-menu?rq=1