# My Windows 10 doesn't show the desktop and start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I downloaded and installed Windows 10 Pro 32 bit.

Occasionally after I start the computer, it boots as usual but then doesn't show the start menu or desktop icons.

After I restart it 2 or 3 times it then works perfectly.

At first I thought it was a graphics card problem, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

My PC is an HP Compaq DC5750 with 2GB RAM; small form factor.

Comment: When you turn it on and nothing happens wait some time to see if it may still work.

Comment: THANX FOR THE ANSWER . I wait like 5 minutes and nothing happens. I have to restart it 3 times and then windows boot  and work perfect .

Answer (score 1):

Open powershell in admin. (Winkey-X, A, accept the admin elevation, then type powershell in the elevated cmd window and press enter.)

Once you have an Administrator Powershell window, run this command:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Reboot.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this solved the problem here. To other users, I'd probably look at trying this first before anything more drastic.

Comment: Yes, as long as you have admin privs, this is the lowest-cost solution.  It certainly doesn't always work, but it fixes one of the causes of the no-start-menu or no-Windows-store bugs.

Answer (score 0):

impossible to tell you what exactly the problem is. Could be a hardware problem but could also be a driver issue. Win10 is known to sometimes overwrite good drivers with bad ones.

Definitely check the windows event logs, you might find specific information there.

Further, I suggest:

1. do a thorough memory test.
2. monitor the temperature of your components, especially the cpu.
3. manually check for newer drivers.

Comment: Ok thanx ill try this .

Answer (score 0):

There is several easy ways to try to fix it in this page:

http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532

But the only one that worked for me was disabling Powershell 2 as someone suggested in the comments:
Control Panel -> Programes and Features -> Turn Window Features On or Off -> disable Powershell 2

It will take a couple of minutes and then you need to restart Windows, and the Start Menu returned.